# ODATA 4J Post Method with basic authentication

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, odata4j

I'm currently new to programming and i'm studying odata4j
I just want to ask how to use get and post method in ODATA 4J with basic authentication and x-csrf-token.

I searched in internet but all the possible code I tried is not working.

here's a code snippet I found.

```
   public ODataClientRequest transform(ODataClientRequest request) {
        if(request.getMethod().equals("GET")){
            request = request.header("X-CSRF-Token", "Fetch");
            return request;
        }else{
            request = request.header("X-CSRF-Token", this.xcsrfToken);
            return request;
        }

    }
```

I tried to use this but I'm confused. How can I set the get method on request variable? Also, how can I set the url and basic authentication on it? Lastly, how can I execute it?

I'm using eclipse

Answer (score 0):

To access the web service you just need to add the basic HTTP authentification to the configuration as follows:

```
ODataClient client = ODataClientFactory.getClient();

// add the configuration here
client.getConfiguration()
    .setHttpClientFactory(new BasicAuthHttpClientFactory("[username]", "[password]"));

String iCrmServiceRoot = "https://example.dev/Authenticated/Service";
ODataServiceDocumentRequest odClientReq = 
client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getServiceDocumentRequest(iCrmServiceRoot)
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks @MBaev quick question, how can I get a csrf using get method?

Comment: I think this may help you https://blogs.sap.com/2012/10/12/how-to-handle-csrf-while-consuming-gateway-services-using-odata4j/
I'm not so familiar with this freemorr, but I'm trying to help you with whatever I can